# How to detect if MiniProfiler is enabled or disabled in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-mini-profiler

In my Rails 4 app I created these two helper functions:

```
def link_to_switch_off_miniprofiler
  link_to "OFF", "?pp=disable"
end

def link_to_switch_on_miniprofiler
  link_to "ON", "?pp=enable"
end
```

Is there any way to detect if [MiniProfiler](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler) is currently enabled or disabled, so I can combine my two functions into one?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: looks like a good candidate: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb#L80

Comment: can you check `params['pp']` to find out whether MiniProfiler is enabled or disabled?